# Sharepoint designer branding

Tags: sharepoint-designer, branding

I'm a beginner in sharepoint designer 2010 and I'm really short on time to learn, so, where is the best source to learn the main default classes and controls so I can edit in a custom CSS file and apply my branding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comprehensive list of CSS classes applied in SP 2010 has been put together by Heather Solomon and can be found at http://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html

Comment: That is the best reference that I know!